# Override Log.Write in Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

What I am trying to do is pass multiple parameters to Log.Write without first creating a long string of them with newline escape characters.

Here is my current function:

```
public static void LogPipedEvent(string message)
    {
        //Split message on double pipe escape "||"
        string newmessage = "";
        string[] splitMessage = Regex.Split(message, Regex.Escape("||"));

        foreach (string line in splitMessage)
        {
            newmessage += "\r\n" + line;
        }
        Logger.Write(newmessage, "DebugCategory", 2, 4000, TraceEventType.Information, "Message");
    }
```

It works fine for what I need it to do but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to break up the "message" portion of the log and have each entry get it's own line within Enterprise library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your delimiter is `||` and you simply need to replace it with new lines, you can use `string.Replace`:

```
public static void LogPipedEvent(string message)
{
    Logger.Write(message.Replace("||", "\r\n"), "DebugCategory", 2, 4000, TraceEventType.Information, "Message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of information that you want to log then you could consider using the LogEntry's [ExendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.logentry.extendedproperties%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx).  The ExtendedProperties is a Dictionary of key/value pairs.

So instead of passing in a pipe delimited string, you could pass in a string and a Dictionary and use a Formatter to output the message in your desired format (out key/value can be on it's own line).

I'm not sure if that fits with the type of data you are dealing with but that is an "Enterprise Library-ish" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your signature? If you did this:

```
public static void LogMessage(params string[] messages)
{
    string message = messages.Join("\r\n");
    Logger.Write(newmessage, "DebugCategory", 2, 4000, TraceEventType.Information, "Message"););
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
LogMessage("Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3");
```